# Convert a string to JSON object

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have a JsonString:

```
"baseAbilities":"[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]"
```

I want to make it:

```
"baseAbilities":[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]
```

So the it is easy for JSON utility to deserialise it. Any suggestions

EDIT:

This is basically a json object in the following Json String:

{"data”: [{"id":9,"name":"Sam5","baseAbilities":"[{\"baseId\":1,\"name\":\"Focused Elemental Strike\"},{\"baseId\":9,\"name\":\"Cleanse\"}]"]}

The backend developer saved JSON in a column baseAbilities as a string. Now I don't have the access to Back end APIs. So i need to convert this string baseAbilities to JSON so that I can access objects inside it.

Now I use these classes to decode JSON:

```
[System.Serializable]
    class GetBAResult
    {
        public List<bounceAbilityData> data;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    class bounceAbilityData
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string baseAbilities;
    }
```

And this is how I decode JSON:

```
GetBAResult P = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetBAResult>(w.text);
        for (int i = 0; i < P.data.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(P.data[i].name);
            GameObject layoutGroupNameButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabBAButton);
            layoutGroupNameButton.transform.SetParent(ParentPanel, false);
            layoutGroupNameButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = P.data[i].name;
            layoutGroupNameButton.GetComponent<BounceAbilityButton>().id = P.data[i].id;
            layoutGroupNameButton.GetComponent<BounceAbilityButton>().name = P.data[i].name;
            Debug.Log(P.data[i].baseAbilities);
        }
```

I need to get things inside baseAbilities such as "baseID" and "name"

Comment: I am writing a solution for this but how did you get that first string in your question? Where is it coming from?

Comment: @Programmer I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: The edit confused me. You have 3 json data in your question, which one are you receiving from the server right now?

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Comment: @ColinM That wouldnt work too. Unity Json does not support Dictionary

Comment: The answer provides the information on deserialization, not an exact answer using data types which weren't defined at the time of the answer. You'd replace the `T` of `FromJson<T>()` with the actual type to deserialize to.

Comment: Answer updated for the new JSON text & data type

Comment: You should look at the `fixJson` function in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original questions says that you want to change:

```
"baseAbilities":"[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]"
```

to

```
"baseAbilities":[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]
```

Basically, you want to remove the `"` before the `[{"` then remove the final `"` at the end of the json string. The problem is that even after you do this, `"baseAbilities":[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]` cannot be serialized to json.

You need to add `{` in front of it and `}` at the end of it.

The final string after adding `{` in front of it and `}` at the end is:

`{"baseAbilities":[{"baseId":1,"name":"Focused Elemental Strike"}]}`

The `fixJson` function below fixes those problems and this is how to use it:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class BaseAbility
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GetBAResult
{
    public List<BaseAbility> baseAbilities;
}

void Start()
{
    // StartCoroutine(RespawnPlayer());

    string fixedJson = fixJson(w.text);
    //string fixedJson = fixJson("\"baseAbilities\":\"[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Focused Elemental Strike\"}]\"");
    Debug.Log("Fixed Json: " + fixedJson);


    GetBAResult P = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetBAResult>(fixedJson);
    Debug.Log("Count Json: " + P.baseAbilities.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < P.baseAbilities.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + P.baseAbilities[i].name);
        Debug.Log("Base ID: " + P.baseAbilities[i].id);
    }
}


string fixJson(string jsonToFix)
{
    //First srting with `"` that will be removed
    const string firstString = "\"baseAbilities\":\"";
    //Last string with `"` that will be removed  
    const string lastString = "\"";

    //String that will be used to fix the "baseAbilities":"[ with the `"`
    const string fixedFirstString = "\"baseAbilities\":";

    //Get the first Index of firstString
    int firstIndex = jsonToFix.IndexOf(firstString);
    //Remove First Index of `firstString` 
    jsonToFix = jsonToFix.Remove(firstIndex, firstString.Length);

    int lastIndex = jsonToFix.LastIndexOf(lastString);
    //Remove everything from Last `lastString` to the end
    jsonToFix = jsonToFix.Remove(lastIndex);

    //Append the correct/fixed string without `"` to the beginning of the json data
    jsonToFix = fixedFirstString + jsonToFix;

    //Add `{` to the begging and `}` to the end of the json data
    jsonToFix = "{" + jsonToFix + "}";

    return jsonToFix;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this?

```
 JObject json = JObject.Parse(str);
```

[documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Comment: For the up-voters, this won't work in Unity due to Unity's .NET version. I don't think this is what OP is asking. OP simply wants to remove `"` from the json string.

Answer (score 1):

With a class set of

```
[System.Serializable]
class GetBAResult
{
    public List<bounceAbilityData> data;
}

[System.Serializable]
class bounceAbilityData
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public List<BaseAbilities> baseAbilities;
}

[System.Serializable]
class BaseAbilities
{
    public int baseId;
    public string name;
}
```

You can then use the following to Deserialize your JSON to an instance of `GetBAResult`

```
string json = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Sam5\",\"baseAbilities\":[{\"baseId\":1,\"name\":\"Focused Elemental Strike\"},{\"baseId\":9,\"name\":\"Cleanse\"}]}]}";
GetBAResult myObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetBAResult>(json);
BaseAbilities abilities = myObject.data[0].baseAbilities[0];
```

You can read more about JSON Deserialization here on the Unity Documentation
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a class like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class JsonTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Ability
    {
        public int baseId;
        public string name;

        public Ability(int _baseId, string _name) 
        {
            baseId = _baseId;
            name = _name;
        }
    }

    public class Abilities
    {
        public List<Ability> baseAbilities;

        public Abilities(List<Ability> _baseAbilities)
        {
            baseAbilities = _baseAbilities;
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        List<Ability> list = new List<Ability>();
        list.Add(new Ability(1, "Focused Elemental Strike"));
        list.Add(new Ability(2, "Another ability"));

        Abilities baseAbilities = new Abilities(list);

        string serializedAbilites = JsonUtility.ToJson(baseAbilities);

        Debug.Log(serializedAbilites);

        Abilities deserializedAbilites = JsonUtility.FromJson<Abilities>(serializedAbilites);
    }
}
```

You have an Ability class marked as *Serializable* containing and id and a name.

You have another class Abilities used as a wrapper for a list of abilities.

You can then serialize a list of abilities using JsonUtility.ToJson(). Which will give you the following string:

```
{
  "baseAbilities": [
    {
      "baseId": 1,
      "name": "Focused Elemental Strike"
    },
    {
      "baseId": 2,
      "name": "Another ability"
    }
  ]
}
```

And of course you can deserialize it using JsonUtility.FromJson().

Is this what your looking for ?